# Galaxy s7 edge. I want to receive and send emails. NOT SYNCHRONISE. How please?

Tags: sync, email, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I need to keep emails on my S7 Edge that relate to current, active projects only. Some have short timelines, some are months long. I want to be able to receive emails and send them but NOT keep getting emails that are archived. Those go to my corporate computer which holds all the emails. So synchronising isn't the answer. I get all the emails all the time plus it's chewing up tons of data when I'm out of office. The emails only get deleted from the mail server (not exchange, pop) when they're downloaded to the corporate computer. Worse, the sent emails don't synchronise at all, not from the sent folder, so I wind up bcc myself (which is what I prefer), but then I get the emails twice - once for sent folder and once in the inbox. It's a royal pain. So ideally, I'd like only the NEW emails to be pushed (or pulled) into the S7 and when I answer, I'll bcc - which puts them back on the server to go to the corporate system when I get into the office. Then I can delete them. BUT that also means I retain copies on my S7 for as long as I need them. BlackBerry 10 used to do that just fine, as it never really synched with Outlook. On the S7, syncing is overkill and difficult to manage. Frankly, I don't believe all the emails are co-ordinating. But my way, they do.

Ideas, anyone?

(Sorry, no gmail, hotmail, outlook.com, live.com etc. - just my phone and pc-based Outlook 2013.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the protocol from POP to IMAP